# Anyone have any idea how I can recreate this sort of lighting/color?

Tags: photoshop, studio-lighting

This is a shot by Ben Hassett, he doesn't use much photoshop as he generally tries to stick to traditional photographic methods when working. Ive been trying to figure out what sort of lighting/technique he used to make all those colors come out in the skin...

**WARNING: Image(s) NSFW and some home viewing** : http://www.benhassett.com/post/46087080962/andreia-and-alice-contreiras-for-exhibition [NSFW]

*Dead link, see http://agonistica.com/andreia-and-alice-by-ben-hassett*

Any suggestions greatly appreciated!

Comment: You should probably link to the original photo rather than download it and then upload an unauthorized copy.

Comment: Also might be worth a NSFW tag before the link, luckily I was home at the time.

Comment: Please see [PSA on “What's this effect?” questions](http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3881/psa-on-whats-this-effect-questions) for some help on asking this kind of question in a way which gets good results and which is helpful to future visitors. Thank you!

Comment: So sorry guys, I should have indeed added a NSFW with this post. Apologies to anyone who opened the link at work or around children.

Comment: Link is now dead; do you have an updated one?

Comment: Link is still dead

Comment: Added a new one

Answer (score 5):

Based on not only the single image you originally linked, but the others that also appear in the post at [Frank Updates](http://frankupdates.com/?p=9602) [NSFW] as well as the photographer's [own page](http://www.benhassett.com/) [NSFW], it's fairly obvious there is a lot of oil of some kind on the skin of the models. The color tint of the oil used probably added a color cast as well as the other, more obvious effects (reflections, body hair stuck to skin, etc). The faces, elbows, and hands are areas that would tend to have the oil brushed away first and these areas show less of the effect than other areas. The models do appear to have spent some time in the sun tanning with certain selected areas not exposed to the Sun's rays. In addition to the oil there also appears to be some theatrical makeup applied. Use of silver tinted light modifiers also appears to have been used to give the shots the 'metallic' look. The catchlights in the head shot indicates the lighting was very directional and above and slightly left of camera.

Based on viewing other works in his [portfolio](http://www.artandcommerce.com/C.aspx?VP3=CMS3&VF=AAC_HomePage#/CMS3&VF=AACAC3_44_VForm&FRM=Frame:AAC_FramePortfolio&ARID=2U1XC520TAHG) [NSFW], I'd also say there is more post processing in terms of color saturation and contrast here than is typical with Ben Hassett's work.

Answer (score 2):

> Ive been trying to figure out what sort of lighting/technique he used to make all those colors come out in the skin...

1. Make up.
2. Lights. I think he might have used a strip box for the effect on the nose and chin. Not sure about the rest.

These are just guesses. One reason why my point 2 is so vague -- it is done relatively subtle.